# PHP CLI My function doesnt work - Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function test()

Tags: php

I have problem with script.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function test() in /home/sss/test.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/sss/test.php on line 3
```

I tried all...
Please help me.

```php
<?php
if (php_sapi_name() == "cli") {
    test('test text');
    function test($text) {
        echo $text;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you call test before you declare it. Code (for the most part) is synchronous and read line-by-line.

Comment: Functions in `if` branches __must be__ defined prior to usage.

Comment: On the web page (without "php_sapi_name...) this code works good, why?

Comment: Also, beware of the lack of opcode caching with conditional functions - it may slow-down your code/application quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the function inside the condition

```php
if (php_sapi_name() == "cli") {
    test('test text');
}

function test($text) {
  echo $text;
}
?>
```